# Don't understand why my Activate function fails in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FindMatch()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Worksheets("Member data").Activate
    Columns("T:T").Select
    Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:="arabinow@gmail.com", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Nothing")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Something)
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep getting Runtime error 1004
Activate method of worksheet class failed
I definitely have a sheet in my workbook called "Member data"

I ran the sub and expected that sheet to be the active sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try it without using Activate or Select:

```
Sub FindMatch()
Dim Cell As Range

With Worksheets("Member data")
    Set Cell = Columns("T:T").Find(What:="arabinow@gmail.com", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Cell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Nothing")
        Else
            Debug.Print Cell.Address
            MsgBox ("Something")
        End If
End With
    
End Sub
```